# Aggregate by several keys

Tags: python

I have this rather verbose piece of code. How can I get it shorter and simpler?

This function aggregate results of test by population and by different keys:

```
def aggregate(f):
  """ Aggregate population by several keys """
  byMerchant  = col.defaultdict(lambda: col.defaultdict(lambda: [0,0,0,0]))
  byPlat      = col.defaultdict(lambda: col.defaultdict(lambda: [0,0,0,0]))
  byDay       = col.defaultdict(lambda: col.defaultdict(lambda: [0,0,0,0]))
  byAffiliate = col.defaultdict(lambda: col.defaultdict(lambda: [0,0,0,0]))
  byCountry   = col.defaultdict(lambda: col.defaultdict(lambda: [0,0,0,0]))
  byType      = col.defaultdict(lambda: col.defaultdict(lambda: [0,0,0,0]))
  byPop       = col.defaultdict(lambda: [0,0,0,0])
  for line in f:
    fields = line.strip().split("^A")
    if fields[2] == '\\N':  continue

    day          = fields[0]
    popid        = int(fields[1])
    affiliate_id = int(fields[2])
    merchant_id  = int(fields[3])
    clicks       = int(fields[4])
    displays     = int(fields[5])
    sales        = float(fields[6])
    gross        = float(fields[7])

    merchant_plat = partners_info[merchant_id][1]
    merchant_name = partners_info[merchant_id][0]

    publisher_name    = publisher_info[affiliate_id][0]
    publisher_country = publisher_info[affiliate_id][1]
    publisher_type    = publisher_info[affiliate_id][2]

    data = [clicks,displays,sales,gross]
    for k in xrange(len(data)):
      byMerchant[merchant_name][popid][k]    += data[k]
      byPlat[merchant_plat][popid][k]        += data[k]
      byAffiliate[publisher_name][popid][k]  += data[k]
      byCountry[publisher_country][popid][k] += data[k]
      byDay[day][popid][k]                   += data[k]
      byType[publisher_type][popid][k]       += data[k]
      byPop[popid][k]                        += data[k]

return byPop, byMerchant, byPlat, byDay, byAffiliate, byCountry, byType
```

Answer (score 1):

If I try to split on the empty string I get an error:

```
>>> 'a b c'.split('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: empty separator
```

Perhaps you meant `.split()`?

Anyway, here are some ideas for simplifying your code.

1. Use `from collections import defaultdict` to avoid the need to refer to `col` (I presume you have `import collections as col`).
2. Put a dummy key into the `byPop` aggregation so that its structure matches the others.
3. Put the aggregates into a dictionary instead of having a bunch of variables. That way you can manipulate them systematically in loops.
4. Use `enumerate` in your last loop to get the index as well as the value from the `data` list.

That leads to this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def aggregate(f):
    """
    Aggregate population by several keys.
    """
    aggregates = 'pop merchant plat day affiliate country type'.split()
    result = dict()
    for a in aggregates:
        result[a] = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: [0,0,0,0]))

    for line in f:
        fields = line.strip().split()
        if fields[2] == '\\N': continue

        # Decode fields from this record.
        day          = fields[0]
        popid        = int(fields[1])
        affiliate_id = int(fields[2])
        merchant_id  = int(fields[3])
        clicks       = int(fields[4])
        displays     = int(fields[5])
        sales        = float(fields[6])
        gross        = float(fields[7])

        # Keys under which to aggregate the data from this record.
        keys = dict(merchant = partners_info[merchant_id][0],
                    plat = partners_info[merchant_id][1],
                    day = day,
                    affiliate = publisher_info[affiliate_id][0],
                    country = publisher_info[affiliate_id][1],
                    type = publisher_info[affiliate_id][2],
                    pop = 0)       # dummy key

        # Update all aggregates.
        for i, value in enumerate([clicks, displays, sales, gross]):
            for a in aggregates:
                result[a][keys[a]][popid][i] += value

    return (result['pop'][0],) + tuple(result[a] for a in aggregates[1:])
```

It's not really a vast improvement.

Comment: The split is on a special character, sorry it has been striped during copy and paste. It is a good idea to directly import the dictionary. I did not think about the dummy key. It makes it possible to factor the code. Thank you. The resulting code is quite complex though.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't simplify it all that much, sorry! Maybe some other person will have some better ideas.